# What is the best way to animate a jumping motion in Unity 3D?

Tags: 3d, animation, unity

I am creating a a simple 3D game in Unity with a character who runs, walks, jumps, swims, shoots etc. I am pretty satisfied with my results in all the motions except jump. I need to know at what height my character is at in relation to the ground at all times (The height of my terrain varies) in order for me to be able to tell the Animator Controller when to transition. I have done some research on the matter and I found out about Raycast but I'm not sure how to use it. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Look into IK Rigging, you can get nice animations using that, just a thought but it might be worth the look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were dealing with plain terrain, it would be easier to calculate, but with a complex terrain such the one you have starting height that differs from the landing height gives you very limited choices, and RayCasting is probably the best among them.

The idea is simple, on every frame of your animation you have to RayCast from the bottom of your character (or its collider, it's up to you the distance you want to calculate), in direction [Vector3.down](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-down.html) and use the distance from that point to the terrain surface to speed up your animation the way you like. **Unity raycasting class already provides you with the distance from the point you have raycasted from and the point you have hit**, the code is therefore very short:

```
Vector3 characterBottomPosition; //initialize this with thebottom position of you character or its collider
    void Update(){
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray downRay = new Ray(characterBottomPosition, -Vector3.up);
        // if the raycast hits something
        if (Physics.Raycast(downRay, out hit)) {
            float distanceFromGround = hit.distance;
            // do your animation stuff here
        }
    }
```

**Please be aware of two things:** the terrain object must have a collider in order to "be hit", otherwise you might have to [implement your own raycasting system](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/raycast-without-colliders.14378/) (which could be extremely time consuming and painful), and also Raycasts will not detect Colliders for which the Raycast origin is inside the Collider, be sure to stop your animation in time before the point from which you are raycasting gets below the terrain.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer that you are looking for as I could use some more specifics, however, the best way to actually go about animating a jump animation is to break it into 3 parts; the "Jump Start", the "Jump Loop" and the "Jump End". 
The Jump Start is where the character is animated jumping into the air, the loop is the movement he makes while "falling" and the Jump End is the impact with the ground. The reason this is the best approach is because it allows you to vary the height of the jump without having to preemptively know how long the player is going to be in the air for. For example, if the player jumps off the top of a building to land on the ground, versus jumping from the ground to a medium height platform. The hold time is different for each.

Hopefully this is what you were asking.

Comment: This helps, thank you, but what I really need to know is how to tell when the player leaves or returns to the ground.

Comment: Ahh. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with Unity in particular as I use UE4. That said, there should be an event pre-coded into the engine that looks for the player's state of "Walking" or "In Air". This is how UE4 does it and I'd imagine its the same in Unity. Hopefully someone else can give you some better direction on where to find this.